# sed + match directory PATH from line by sed

Tags: sed

hi have in file the example line: (in file)

PATH: word1 /var/tmp word2 word3

how to rescue or match only  "/var/tmp" PATH from the line by sed

remark: /var/tmp its only example , it could  be any other path!

remark1: /var/tmp could be in the first line or in the end of the line or somewhere in the middle of line

for example

```
 echo "PATH: word1 /var/tmp word2 word3" | sed ...
```

will print

```
/var/tmp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat file
PATH: word1 /var/tmp word2 word3
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i ~/\//) print $i}' file
/var/tmp
```

This does not work if you have directory names with spaces. Provide a more concrete example of the possible paths that you might have. best of all, tackle the root of the problem at the source, where you got your data from.

Answer (score -1):

`echo 'PATH: word1 /var/tmp word2 word3' | cut -d ' ' -f 3`

Comment: The OP said that the path is not always in the same spot within a line.

Comment: That's not a problem, it appears you haven't tested my solution. 
The cut simply selects the third space-delimited field. The only situation in which this would not work is when there are spaces in the path.